# Send command output through filecontents

Tags: bibtex, titles, filecontents

#### General situation

In a document I have to mention bibliographic line and corresponding BibTeX blockcode of the document itself.

Then, some fields of the BibTeX code, like `title` `author` `date`, should not be hard-coded but should depend of the corresponding LaTeX command definitions.

#### What I did

In order to get this behavior, I made the following BibTeX block code definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{
 @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
    title  = {\@title},
    author = {\@author},
    publisher = {MadPublisher},
    year = {\@date}
 }
}
\makeatother
```

As you see, the `title` `author` `year`’s value are given by the `\@title` `\@author` `\@year` commands inside a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` context.

#### Where the problem is set

The problem start just next when I put this command in a `filecontents` environment:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
\bibtexselfentry
\end{filecontents*}
```

Because the file created by filecontents do not contain the bib block as expected but literally the following content:

```
\bibtexselfentry
```

So, the consequences is BibTeX can’t find `fauve2023TheSuperBook` and act like if it doesn’t exist (in fact it doesn’t exist in the bib file).

#### Some explanations

The `filecontents` environment put in `jobname.bib` the literal content I give him. Hi doesn’t interpret it.

#### The question

Is it possible to give to `filecontents` the output of some commands to make him don’t print the literal command name?

Alternatively, is their any other way to give a bibfile some values depending of a command output instead of hard coding the values?

---

## Appendix

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\title{The Super Book}
\author{Fauve}
\date{3 June 2023}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{
 @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
    title  = {\@title},
    author = {\@author},
    publisher = {MadPublisher},
    year = {\@date}
 }
}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
\bibtexselfentry
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
You can cite this work with:

\fullcite{fauve2023TheSuperBook}
\vspace{1cm}

Using the following Bib\TeX block:

\texttt
\bibtexselfentry



\end{document}
```

#### Expected rendering

[image: Expected rendering]

#### Obtained rendering

[image: Obtained rendering]

Comment: BTW: Package `filecontents` is obsolete and should result in a corresponding warning message, when using an up-to-date LaTeX. See LaTeX News Issue 30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with you approach. First of all, `filecontents` has not been made to expand anything while writing. It has been made to write the contents of the environment *verbatim*, which means without any expansion.

Also, writing the definition of `\bibtexselfentry` to the file, would not help, because it would generate the content:

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook, title  = {\@title},    author = {\@author}, publisher = {MadPublisher},     year = {\@date} }
```

But with class `article`, `\@title`, `\@author` and `\@date` are not longer valid after `\maketitle`. `\maketitle` redefines them empty. Just add `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}` to see it.

So you need a real expansion like here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{The Super Book}
\author{Fauve}
\date{3 June 2023}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{
 @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
    title  = {\@title},
    author = {\@author},
    publisher = {MadPublisher},
    year = {\@date}
 }
}
\makeatother

\newwrite\mybibfile
\immediate\openout\mybibfile \jobname.bib
\immediate\write\mybibfile{\bibtexselfentry}
\immediate\closeout\mybibfile

\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

You can cite this work with:

\fullcite{fauve2023TheSuperBook}
\vspace{1cm}

Using the following Bib\TeX block:

\texttt
\bibtexselfentry

\end{document}
```

which produces a `bib` file:

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook, title = {The Super Book}, author = {Fauve}, publisher = {MadPublisher}, year = {3 June 2023} }
```

I've also removed package `filecontents`, which is obsolete for years and also not needed in your example. With an up-to-date LaTeX the package shows the warning:

```
Package filecontents Warning: This package is obsolete. Disabling it and
(filecontents)                passing control to the filecontents environment
(filecontents)                defined by the LaTeX kernel.
```

And I've replaces `jobname.bib` by `\jobname.bib`, because I do not think, that you want to write a file `jobname.bib` but a `bib` file with the basename of the current TeX job.

The shown example can be improved, by writing end-of-line characters to the `bib` file, e.g. using

```
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{%
 @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,^^J%
    title  = {\@title},^^J%
    author = {\@author},^^J%
    publisher = {MadPublisher},^^J%
    year = {\@date}^^J%
 }%
}
```

to write:

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
title = {The Super Book},
author = {Fauve},
publisher = {MadPublisher},
year = {3 June 2023}
}
```

Maybe using `\protected@write` resp. an immediate version of it would also be a good idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlfile}% provides \protected@immediate@write
\usepackage{listings}
\title{The Super Book}
\author{Fauve\and \textsc{Me}}
\date{3 June 2023}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{%
 @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,^^J%
    title  = {\@title},^^J%
    author = {\@author},^^J%
    publisher = {MadPublisher},^^J%
    year = {\@date}^^J%
 }%
}

\newwrite\mybibfile
\immediate\openout\mybibfile \jobname.bib
\begingroup
\def\and{\string\and\space}
\protected@immediate@write\mybibfile{}{\bibtexselfentry}
\immediate\closeout\mybibfile
\makeatother

\RequirePackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

You can cite this work with:

\fullcite{fauve2023TheSuperBook}
\vspace{1cm}

Using the following Bib\TeX block:

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

Note: If you want to do some indent of some codes, you can also use

```
\newcommand\bibtexselfentry{%
  @book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,^^J
  \space title  = {\@title},^^J
  \space author = {\@author},^^J
  \space publisher = {MadPublisher},^^J
  \space year = {\@date}^^J%
  }%
}
```

which would result in:

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
  title = {The Super Book},
  author = {Fauve\and \protect \textsc  {Me}},
  publisher = {MadPublisher},
  year = {3 June 2023}
}
```

resp. (without my changes of `\author` in the last example):

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
  title = {The Super Book},
  author = {Fauve},
  publisher = {MadPublisher},
  year = {3 June 2023}
}
```

The first space to indent the lines is from the end of line character after the `^^J`, the second one from the `\space` command.

I would also recommend to use `backend=biber`. The legacy interface using `backend=bibtex` has a reduced functionality and is not supported by all third-party styles.

Comment: Useful answer. Just need one little improvement: is it an equivalent to “^^J” but for making tabulation?

Comment: @fauve You can, e.g., use `\space` to add spaces to the output. Or just remove the `%` after the `^^J` to have one space.